# How to get the detail of github users with search api using KnpLabs/php-github-api v3 client

Tags: laravel-8, github-api, github-api-v3

I am stuck in a scenario where i need to show the listing of all git hub user. So i am using below github api to get the list of users-

```
https://api.github.com/search/users?q=type:user
```

But it didn't giving me complete detail of user **like: username, bio, followers** etc. So to get this i need to call another below api to get each user detail inside loop-

```
https://api.github.com/users/mojombo
```

Seems not a good way to get the every user detail again i need to call another api inside loop. Please help me anyone is their any good way to achieve this.

**API Version** : GitHub API v3 client

Thanks in advance.